# How can I save database changes in Docker to the server?

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, docker, database, xampp

I am using the **[tomsik68/xampp docker](https://github.com/tomsik68/docker-xampp)** image on my Linux server.

When I restart my server or remove the container (via the docker rm myXampp), all database changes are lost. How do I save database changes to the server?

This is the database location in the docker image:

```
"/opt/lampp/var/mysql"
```

I ran the container with this code:

```
docker run --name myXampp -p 3999:22 -p 4000:80 -d -v ~/myWebPages:/opt/lampp/htdocs tomsik68/xampp
```

I want all database changes to save to server. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "save to server", you mean persisting your database contents across subsequent container runs, you have to [create a Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in which your data will be stored.

Similarly to how you mount your web pages to the `htdocs` directory, you can:

- choose any database directory on your local machine, or
- have Docker create a named volume for you (e.g. `xamppdb`).

For example:

```
docker run --name myXampp \
    -p 3999:22 -p 4000:80 -d \
    -v ~/myWebPages:/opt/lampp/htdocs \
    -v xamppdb:/opt/lampp/var/mysql \
    tomsik68/xampp
```

That assumes the `/opt/lampp/var/mysql` contents should be persisted.